# How to notify all admins by selecting the status_id of the records from the specified table when the user updated the record via e-mail

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-query-builder, laravel-notification

I using Laravel 7 and I have the **topics** table that I have 5 status these statuses
they are the foreign key from the statuses table.

**Topics Table**

| id | topic | owner_id | status_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | B | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | C | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | D | 4 | 6 |

**Statuses Table**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Draft |
| 2 | Waiting for topic approval |
| 3 | Edit the topic |
| 4 | Do not approve the topic |
| 5 | Approved topic |
| 6 | Waiting for scoring |
| 7 | Approved score |

I want to notify all admins (user_role=1 on the User Table)
when users update a record where status_id = 2 or 6 via e-mail.

[image]

Thank you in advance. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Comment: how will you notify the admins?? via email??

Comment: Get all admins from the database and then [send each one a notification](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#sending-notifications).

Comment: @zahidhasanemon via e-mail sir.

Comment: @apokryfos I tried but I don't understand clearly and I don't make it happen that's why I posted this topic, sir.

Comment: You need to make an attempt to solve this yourself. If you can't manage it then share the code with your attempt and then we can help you. I suggest (a) [create a mail notification](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#mail-notifications) (b) get all admins from database, (c) loop over each admin and  [send a new instance of the notification](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#sending-notifications). The laravel boilerplate already ensures users are notifiable. If you have problems after you've written code attempting to do this then update your question with the code that fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say a user is editing Topic with id 1.

```
// import classes in your controller
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use App\Notifications\TopicUpdateNotification;
 
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // some validation if needed

    $topic = Topic::find($id);
    $status = $topic->status_id;
    $topic->update([
        'topic' => $request->topic,
        // add any other column you want to update
    ]);
    
    // now we are checking if the topic status was 2 or 6
    if ($status == 2 || $status == 6) {
        // finding all the admins
        $admins = User::where('user_role', 1)->get();
        $user = auth()->user();
        // sending notification via Notification Facade
        Notification::send($admins, new TopicUpdateNotification($topic, $user));
    }
}
```

we have used a class named `TopicUpdateNotification`. this is a notification class and we have to create it with the artisan command.

```
php artisan make:notification TopicUpdateNotification
```

you will find it in your project's `app/Notifications` directory. content for this class

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class TopicUpdateNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($topic, $user)
    {
        $this->topic = $topic;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
        ->view(
            'topic_update_email', ['topic' => $this->topic, 'user' => $this->user]
        )
        ->from('support@yourcompany.com', 'Your Company Name') // you can omit this line if you have valid MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS and MAIL_FROM_NAME in your .env
        ->subject('Topic Updated');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

and finally make a blade file in the views folder **topic_update_email.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head
<body>
    <h1>User {{ $user->name }} updated the topic {{ $topic->id }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

you can find complete laravel notification doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications)